# Dependency injection to choose between local and remote data

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I need to create a model with dynamic choice of the source of data as a property of a model (code first from database. Code-second).

```
class MyModel{
public int MyModelId {get; set;}
...
public int PropertyId {get;set;}
public virtual Property Property {get;set;} // this what I need to choose.
...
```

The Property need to be get from Property table from a database if in a config file it's set `<property>remote</property>` and from a local container with the same structured as from the database if `<property>local</property>`.

```
class Property{
   public int PropertyId {get;set}
   public string name {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<MyModel> MyModels {get;set;}
   public Property()
   {
       MyModels = new List<Model>();
   }
}
```

and the local data is like

```
 List<Property> lProperty = new List<Property>() 
{{PropertyId = 1,name = "val1"},
{PropertyId = 2,name = "val2"},
{PropertyId = 3,name = "val3"} ...}
```

Comment: Do you have the same horrible formatting in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this case you should refuse from EF relationship and write something like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int MyModelId { get; set; }

    //PropertyId now is not real FK to PropertyTable at DB it is just another column, 
    //but it still will store reference to Property
    public int? PropertyId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Property Property
    {
        get
        {
            if (PropertyId.HasValue)
            {
                if (ForExampleStaticClass.config("property") == "remote")
                    using (var context = new Context())
                    {
                        return context.PropertyTable.Where(x => x.PropertyId == PropertyId.Value).FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                else
                    return ForExampleStaticClass.lProperty.Where(x => x.PropertyId == PropertyId.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        set
        {
            //I consider that Property(value) already exists at DB and/or Local Storage.                          
            PropertyId = value.PropertyId;
        }
    }
}
```